# is there any problem in my minimum number finding?

Tags: arrays, c

The code is to find maximum and minimum number, so i make this code

```
// find maximum and minimum in array
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int values[5];    // I take the size of array as 5
    int i, max = values[0], min = values[0]; // and gives max and min 0
                                             // index position in the array

    printf ("Enter 5 numbers: ");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        scanf ("%d", &values[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (values[i] < min) {
            min = values[i];
        }
        if (values[i] > max) {
            max = values[i];
        }
    }

    printf ("The maximum number is: %d", max);
    printf ("\nThe minimum number is: %d", min);
    return 0;
}
```

everything is fine maximum showing the maximum value but the minimum showing always 0. I need to put values in minus to show minimum values. help please.

Comment: Yes, you initialised them from undefined array values. Do that *after* you input the values. Alternatively `int max = INT_MIN, min = INT_MAX;`

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you very much , i did not think that if i declare index position before taking values then the minimum will always be 0 until I put negative integers. just gathering small knowledge every time.

Comment: You didn't store the array *position* or index as commented in the code, but the actual values. And anyway the value isn't "always 0". Local variables have indeterminate value until explicity assigned.

Comment: Please edit the code and apply sound indention; your braces are all over the place.